# js Экземпляр класса и конструктор

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ооп

Есть класс

```
export  class TreeConverter{
    constructor(data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }
    
    getTree()
    {        
        return // возвращает результат другого метода
    }

}
```

Дело в том, что в нужном компоненте в каждом цикле я каждый раз создаю экземпляр класса, который возвращает мне нужные значения.

```
import {TreeConverter} from "@/mixins/service/tree/union-tree";
///
for(let item of items) {
const converter = new TreeConverter(item);
let res = converter.getTree()
 }
```

Я подумал, что не очень хорошая идея каждый раз создавать новый экземпляр

и попытался засунуть вызов экземпляра класса в data() и потом уже использовать только этот экземпляр в компоненте:

```
 data() {
    return {
      filterData: [], 
      treeUnion: new TreeConverter(this.filterData),
    }
  },

///
this.unionTree(this.filterData).getTree();
```

и получается что входные аргументы в конструктор класса передаются только первый раз при создании (они пустые в начале - undefined, а мне нужно каждую итерацию моего метода в компоненте, передавать в этот единственный экземпляр класса новые данные и что бы метод класса возвращал новый обработанный результат.
Возможно ли это как-то сделать?

Comment: Можете передавать данные не в конструктор, а в метод `getTree`. В итоге у вас получится `this.unionTree().getTree(this.filterData);`. Я даю такой совет только потому, что знаю, как устроен `TreeConverter`. Лучше в вопросе приводить весь код.

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko да, это работает. this.treeUnion.getTree(this.filterData) Но, всё таки, можно ли прокинуть как-то новые данные в конструктор существующего экземпляра?

Comment: Конструктор на то и конструктор, что вызывается один раз при создании экземпляра. Нет, нельзя. Но можете у экземпляра изменить свойства, в вашем случае - `data`.